# SQL separar la descripción por categoria

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola tengo una sentencia sql que me meustra esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero es que la descripción se me divida en grafo o centro de consto en 2 campos diferentes de la tabla , me han sugerido usar CASE pero no tengo muy claro como implementarlo

```
 SELECT 
  item.id_item,
  item.id_rendicion,
  item.fItem,
  item.numdoc,
  item.Total,
  item.imputacion,
  cat.id_cuenta,
  tip.descripcion,
  item.id_TipoImputacion

  FROM dbo.Rendiciones_Item item
  INNER JOIN dbo.Rendiciones_Rendicion rend ON rend.id_Rendicion = 
  item.id_rendicion
  INNER JOIN dbo.Rendiciones_Categoria cat ON item.id_cate = cat.id_Cate
  INNER JOIN dbo.Rendiciones_TipoImputacion tip ON item.id_tipoImputacion = 
  tip.id_TipoImputacion

  WHERE item.id_rendicion= 4567
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con grafo o centro de consto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SI tal cual , para poder dividir un campo en dos segpun sus condiciones, puedes hacerlo con CASE WHEN.

Te paso como podrías llegar a solucionarlo.

```
SELECT 
    item.id_item,
    item.id_rendicion,
    item.fItem,
    item.numdoc,
    item.Total,
    item.imputacion,
    cat.id_cuenta,
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(tip.descripcion,0,5) = 'Grafo' THEN tip.descripcion ELSE '' END as descripcion_grafo,
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(tip.descripcion,0,6) = 'Centro' THEN tip.descripcion ELSE '' END as descripcion_centro,
    item.id_TipoImputacion

    FROM dbo.Rendiciones_Item item
    INNER JOIN dbo.Rendiciones_Rendicion rend ON rend.id_Rendicion =
    item.id_rendicion
    INNER JOIN dbo.Rendiciones_Categoria cat ON item.id_cate = cat.id_Cate
    INNER JOIN dbo.Rendiciones_TipoImputacion tip ON item.id_tipoImputacion =
    tip.id_TipoImputacion

    WHERE item.id_rendicion= 4567
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio bastante :)